# Break a single variable into many

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Hi,

I have a variable in javascript called lists that produces this:

```
Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring
```

but I need to break down that into an array of variables, one per sentence. The only thing that separates each sentence is the quadruple space you see in-between them. Also, I need only the first word of the sentence for each variable in order to get something like this:

```
var sounds = {
  "gasp" : {
    url : "gasp.mp3",
  },
  "giggle" : {
    url : "giggle.mp3",
  },
[...]
  "scream" : {
    url : "scream.mp3",
  },
  "snoring" : {
    url : "snoring.mp3",
  }
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Search for the term "splitting strings", not "breaking variables".

Comment: But what about then the separator is a QUADRUPLE space?

Comment: seems like a simple regular expression.

Comment: If you know there will always be 4 spaces between the phrases .split() will help you separate them into an array. Then loop through the array to create your `sounds` obj. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` to split the string into an array, and then `reduce` to transform the array into an object:

```js
const input = 'Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring';
const sounds = input.split('    ')
  .reduce((accum, str) => {
    const name = str.match(/^([^ ]+)/)[0];
    accum[name] = { url: name + '.mp3' };
    return accum;
  }, {});
console.log(sounds);
```

Comment: thanks but i get something weird in the logs: {…}
​
`Come: Object { url: "Come.mp3" }
​
Gasp: Object { url: "Gasp.mp3" }
​
Giggle: Object { url: "Giggle.mp3" }
​
Kick: Object { url: "Kick.mp3" }
​
Kiss: Object { url: "Kiss.mp3" }
​
Say: Object { url: "Say.mp3" }
​
Scream: Object { url: "Scream.mp3" }
​
Snoring: Object { url: "Snoring.mp3" }
​
Yawn: Object { url: "Yawn.mp3" }
​
__proto__: Object { … }`

Comment: That `object` shouldnt be there, should it?

Comment: Your desired output described your desired output `sounds` as an object of objects, so that's exactly what my posted snippet does. Run your own snippet if you want, it should do the same thing.

Comment: But my question is if the snippet can output the variable sounds as in my question?

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" and you'll see that it matches exactly.

Comment: I see but any idea why it doesnt look like that in the logs?

Comment: If you've copied the snippet exactly and the input matches the format you posted in your question, then the object it's generating is the same, you're just misunderstanding the output text you're getting. Do a JSON.stringify if you want

Comment: does it mean its normal it looks like that in the logs?

Comment: Most likely. I don't know what editor you're using, but whenever you're in doubt about an object's structure, just use JSON.stringify to make sure.

Comment: I didnt I get it. Seems like Im not getting the variable right because the output should be completely in lowercase. Otherwise it wont find the files.

Comment: Call `toLowerCase()` on `name` to turn it into lower case.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry again but Im afraid its not working. The javascript code that utilizes the var "sounds" is not catching it. I guess it has to do with the "object" thing. That is somehow preventing the var from being parsed right.

Comment: This is the snippet im using: `const input = 'Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring';
const sounds = input.toLowerCase().split('    ')
  .reduce((accum, str) => {
    const name = str.match(/^([^ ]+)/)[0];
    accum[name] = { url: name.toLowerCase() + '.mp3' };
    return accum;
  }, {});
console.log(sounds);`

Comment: My code works perfectly for the string you posted in your question. If your string does not actually match what you posted, edit your question. (and try to post your real input the first time, rather than after people answer you...)

Comment: I posted exactly the string I need but Im not getting that with your snippet. I swear. The logs are proof of that . In the logs it says "Object" before every `{`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3tm0fp0/ The code you posted looks fine. If your environment is showing something different and it's breaking the script, that's an issue with your environment, not with the code.

Comment: I checked the fiddle you posted but Im getting the same output as on my site. I am using firefox latest version for the record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170932/discussion-between-certainperformance-and-cain-nuke).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but something came up and I got stuck. The snippet works perfectly if I declare `lists` manually BUT it should actually be declared like this: `var lists = elt.textContent;` I use `console.log(lists);` in order to confirm that the produced string looks like when I input it manually: `Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring` and it DOES but I get this: `TypeError: str.match(...) is null`. Any idea why is that?

Comment: What is `lists` and `elt`, I don't think I've seen those variables before? If that's your new string, it only has one space between each entry, so you can't split by `'    '`, you'll have to identify the words based on the capitalization instead

Comment: yes, I didnt include it here because it was simpler to do it with the produced string.